# How can I use two infinite loop in batch script

Tags: batch-file

How can I use two infinite loop in a batch script..

```
@echo off

:loop

if exist "C:\users\file.txt" (

    mkdir "C:\memory" 2>nul

    if exist "C:\me/file.txt" (

        :again

        mkdir "C:\me\mee" 2>nul

        goto again

    ) 

    goto loop

)

goto loop
```

Comment: What behavior do you expect? Clearly infinite loop is infinite - not sure why to wrap it in another infinite loop...

Answer (score 1):

The label `:again` cannot be called as it is withing a code block, `()`.

The line `if exist "C:\me/file.txt" (` is invalid, a normal `/` is not in paths, but this might be an error in input to stackOverflow.

As well, you only need one loop, and rather a check variable to run the second command over and over.

```
@echo off
:fileLoop
set "intDoMkdir=0"
if exist "C:\users\file.txt" (
    mkdir "C:\memory" 2>nul
    set "intDoMkdir=1"
)
if "%intDoMkdir%" equ "1" (
    if exist "C:\me\file.txt" (
        mkdir "C:\me\mee" 2>nul
    )
)
goto :fileLoop
```